# How to slice multiple columns and sort the values with respect to another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

There are multiple columns in a dataframe.I want to slice three columns and sort them using another column.
I tried something like this.

```
imdb.loc[:5, ['A', 'B','C']].sort_values(['D']) 

O/P:
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can also use [`series.argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) which returns index of sorted values along with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['D'].argsort(),['A','B','C']]
```

---

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  5  0  3  3
1  7  9  3  5
2  2  4  7  6
3  8  8  1  6
4  7  7  8  1

print(df.loc[df['D'].argsort(),['A','B','C']])

   A  B  C
4  7  7  8
0  5  0  3
1  7  9  3
2  2  4  7
3  8  8  1
```

Comment: How to sort in descending order using argsort()

Comment: @Kishan you can choose to reverse the order `print(df.loc[df['D'].argsort()[::-1],['A','B','C']])`

Comment: would [::-1] sort based on highest value?

Comment: @Kishan it gets used after argsort so it should

Answer (score 0):

You can slice all four, sort values and drop

```
imdb.loc[:5, ['A','B','C','D']].sort_values('D').drop('D', axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for answering .It gives an error "KeyError: 'D'"

Comment: great approach thanks i forgot to include drop. But the output is not returning first 5 rows.Instead it retrieves 12 rows why??

Comment: "imdb.loc[:5, ['A','B','C','D']].sort_values('D').drop('D', axis=1)[:5]" nevermind this worked but still if there are any better approach available,it would be much appreciated